# VB6 returns wrong calculations

Tags: vb6

I program in VB6 more than 15 years and today I got a very mysterious bug that made me investigate my variables and I was shocked also when I did this in the immediate window too.

VB6 Immediate Window:

```
?18.21-18.29
-7,99999999999983E-02 
?18.25-18.20
5,00000000000007E-02
```

In the immediate window of vb.net i do not have this problem:

```
?18.21-18.29
-0.0799999999999983
?18.25-18.20
0.050000000000000711
```

So if if numbers like these are assigned to variables in VB6 (tried Single, Double, even Variant - had the same outcome) I get disasterous results.

Am I going crazy over here?? Am I missing something?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Scientific notation? Localization? What is wrong?

Comment: No, I am just comparing two audio files that have 18.21 and 18.29 secs duration and want to get the difference. So expecting a -0.08 or -0.079 i get a -7.9 result!! I could multiply the numbers by 100 i suppose, make the calculation and then divide the outcome to get the proper result as a workaround, but is this valid? Is it explained anywhere why this is the result of the subtraction of two very close singles?

Comment: `E-02` is what you're missing. -7.99999999999983E-02 = -0.0799999999999983

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.  Not what the OP was asking.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The user is actually having floating point to string formatting / conversion issues.  To the OP, be aware that the immediate window is effectively converting that numeric output to a string.  What you need to do is explicitly format the output to see better results.